# latexmk endless loop when non-PDF outputs are specified

Tags: automation, latexmk

My source file is based on the `standalone` package. The `\documentclass` command specifically looks like this:

```
\documentclass[preview, convert={density=300}]{standalone}
```

If the source file is named `main.tex`, compiling it will result in producing the `main.pdf` and `main.png` files.

`latexmk` runs only once the first time `main.png` is created. However, it goes into an endless loop once I begin updating the source file (and hence the `main.pdf` and `main.png`)

I think this is because `latexmk` mistakes the `main.png` file as part of the source for building the final `main.pdf`.

Is there a way to exclude certain files from being monitored by `latexmk`? I searched inside `man latexmk` but there are no occurrences of "exclude".

Comment: At present there is no simple way to exclude files from being monitored.  But this example shows that this would sometimes be a useful feature.  (Note that in the `.fls` file produced by `pdflatex` in the example, the `main.png` file is listed as an input file.  So it is natural for `latexmk` to deduce that `main.png` is a genuine source file.)  I've added the possibility of configuring `latexmk` to exclude specified files from being monitored to my list of proposed future improvements for `latexmk`.

Answer (score 7):

I can reproduce this with `latexmk 4.35`. The issue is that the created `png` file contains date+time created meta-information which changes on every run, and `latexmk` thinks the `png` file is part of the input, not output. I cannot think of an appropriate regular expression for `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'png'}` to really solve this at the right level since `png`s are binary files.

However, I can help you to get `latexmk` to ignore the generated `png` file. The reason why `latexmk` thinks the `png` file is an input to your document is that in `standalone.cls`, there are commands like `\IfFileExists{\outfile` with various forms of file extensions to detect if conversion succeeded. Therefore, as far as `pdflatex` knows, you are reading that file during the run, but it knows nothing about you writing the file as it is done externally to the TeX engine. This information that `pdflatex` has is picked up by `latexmk` through the `recorder` feature. Disabling the `recorder` feature (by adding `-recorder-` to the `latexmk` options) means `latexmk` becomes ignorant of the `png` file and cannot therefore rerun when it changes. I am not aware of any feature in `latexmk` that allows you to specify an 'ignore dependants' list within which you could specifically name the output `png` file.

Also, from the `standalone` manual:

> `standalone` executes the same LaTeX compiler (e.g. `pdflatex`) again as a sub-process which compiles the current document fully. This is done when the standalone class is loaded, so that the main compiler instance is still at `\documentclass` and has not yet itself opened the output file for writing. After the document got compiled using the sub-process the external conversion tool will be executed. If required intermediate conversions like `dvips` are also executed beforehand. Finally the main compiler run is terminated without producing any output, keeping the output file generated by the sub-process intact. A drawback of this implementation is that the `log` file created by the sub-process is overwritten by the main process and does not hold meaningful information. This can be compensated by setting a different `jobname` for the sub-process using the `subjobname` conversion setting.

Note this refers to running `pdflatex` on the subjob, not `latexmk`! As `latexmk` is reliant on the information in the `log` file, we should follow the suggestion of using a different jobname for the sub-process.

There are therefore two steps which together seem to workaround the problem at this stage:

- Use the `subname` option to the `convert` settings in `standalone`.
- Pass the `-recorder-` option to `latexmk` to disable the `recorder` feature of `pdflatex` (so the generated `png` file is not identified as a dependant).

MWE (called `converttest.tex` for the command line given below):

```
\documentclass[preview, convert={density=300,subjobname=\jobname-converted}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    Hello.
\end{document}
```

`latexmk` command line: `latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -recorder- "converttest"`

Then, change the TeX file, perhaps changing `Hello` to `Hello world` and re-run the same `latexmk` command-line. Things work if `-recorder-` is used but not otherwise. But now remember that the output image has a different filename (`-converted` is appended).

Answer (score 3):

The solution using a different subjobname works, at least in the simplest cases. But by not using the recorder option, it doesn't give `latexmk` full knowledge about the dependent files.  Also the actual desired output `.png` file is not produced by a run of `pdflatex` that is directly controlled by `latexmk`, so `latexmk` will could have misleading dependency information: E.g., it will not know the actual `.aux` files used by the run of `pdflatex` producing the `.png` file.

The arrangement used in the original example is that the `standalone` package does a subsidiary run of `pdflatex` with a special command line, and then it runs a program to convert the `.pdf` file to a `.png` file.  An alternative arrangement is to give all that work to `latexmk` with a suitable configuration.  I have a `latexmkrc` file with the following contents:

```perl
$pdf_mode = 1;
$dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;
$pdflatex =
   'pdflatex %O'.
      '"\\expandafter\\def\\csname sa@internal@rune\\endcsname{1}\\input{"%S"}"; '.
   'convert -density 300 %D -quality 90 %R.png';
```

and a document file

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:Emc2}
   E=mc^2.
\end{equation}
See (\ref{eq:Emc2}).
\end{document}
```

Just running `latexmk` on the document file gives the desired result.  No extra options are needed.

Note that the configured command line for `pdflatex` has quoting that works on UNIX-like systems (e.g., OS-X, where I've tested it, and presumably linux).  It will need some changes for MS-Windows.